# Fix Marker position instead map Rotation/ bearing(orientation) like pokemon go

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm working on android app uses map for tracking user location. I want to fix my current location marker on screen. In my current working demo, when I rotate map current location marker hide under screen or move to another position. how should i achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide code wher you work with marker and where you initialise map?

Comment: the code is same we always write for adding marker and animating camera position. I can give u example of what i'm looking for is hv you played ingress game there marker remain on same position but u can rotate map around it.

Comment: Please review these guidelines for asking good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, then you will have to make some hack. Sorry, you didn't provide me code, so I'm unlikely to prompt you the exact solution. But I can explain idea.

The idea that you places two views in FrameLayout: MapView and View (sorry for pseudo code).

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/touch_zone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Thus you can prevent to touch on map. Then you need to make your map track on your position

For example you can catch events when you position changes and call `googleMap.animateCamera(...)`.

Then for touch_zone view you need to call `setOnTouchListener` with your anonymous class, which will handle touch to our upper view. In this method you will implement logic of fetching coordintates on screen making projection to coordinates on map and realise, where you need to rotate your map.

Comment: i haven't write any code except marker placing on map, bcoz i don't know how to do it. so, let me work on your solution. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want the marker to always come back to the center of the screen, you can use:

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(latLng).zoom(zoom).build();

googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
            .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

here, latLng holds the latitude and the longitude of the marker, and every time the position of the marker is changed, or if you want the marker to come back to the center, you can use the above code.

Also, You can prevent the map from being draggable using the following code:

```
googleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
```

This will disable the map to move around, but rotation, panning and zooming works fine.

Comment: I can give u example of what i'm looking for is hv you played ingress game  or pokemon go there marker remain on same position but u can rotate map around it.

Comment: I've played none of the games, but i've seen people playing them. I've updated the answer with what i think does what you want.